# Behat "When I fill the following fields" input todays date?

Tags: php, selenium, behat

Is there a way in behat to get it to input todays date when I fill in a field?

an example

Given I fill in the following fields
| field_date | TODAY |

And I would like the output as dd/mm/YYYY

I cant understand why I cant find it, or find someone else who has done this before? I have found answers for gherkin and cucumber, but nothing for PHP and behat..

Thanks

Comment: you can also use jQuery if you have a date picker

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working...add this to your FormContext file -

```
/**
 * Fills in specified field with date
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "now"
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-7 days"
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "+7 days"
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-/+0 weeks"
 * Example: When I fill in "field_ID" with date "-/+0 years"
 *
 * @When /^(?:|I )fill in "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" with date "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
 */
public function fillDateField($field, $value)
{
    $newDate = strtotime("$value");

    $dateToSet = date("d/m/Y", $newDate);
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField($field, $dateToSet);
}
```